# React JS Filters being overwritten by setState data in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table where I'm setting data inside a useEffect from an api. My filter logic iterates through the "rows" variable which is being set inside this useEffect. However, every-time the user searches via an input which has an onChange event the useEffect setRows I believe is setting the data over and over again.

What would be a better way to set the data so it doesn't conflict with my filtering logic?

//State

```
const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<IDocument[]>([]);
const [rows, setRows] = useState<Data[]>([]);
```

//useEffect to setData

```
useEffect(() => {
//setDocuments from claimStore when component mounts
    setDocuments(claimsStore.getIncomingDocuments());

    //setRows from documents when component mounts
    setRows(
        documents.map((document) =>
        createData(
            document.documentAuthor ?? '',
            document.documentMetadataId.toLocaleString(),
            document.documentMetadataId.toLocaleString(),
            document.documentName ?? '',
            document.documentSource ?? '',
            document.documentType,
            document.featureId ?? '',
            document.mimeType,
            document.uploadDateTime,
        ),
        ),
    ); 
}, [claimsStore, documents]);
```

//Filter logic that updates rows as user input values captured

```
const filterBySearch = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const newFilters = { ...filters, [name]: value };
    //Update filters with user input
    setFilters(newFilters);

    //Filter documents based on user input
    const updatedList = rows.filter((document) => {
        return (
        document.documentAuthor.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentAuthor.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentName.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentName.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentSource.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentSource.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentType.includes(filters.documentType === 'All' ? '' : filters.documentType) &&
        document.featureId.includes(filters.featureId) 
        );
    });

    //Trigger render with updated values
    setRows(updatedList);
};
```

Use of filterBySearch:

```
<TableCell align={'center'} className={classes.tableCell}>
    <input
    value={filters.featureId}
    onChange={(e) => filterBySearch(e)}
    name="featureId"
    className={classes.inputCell}
    />
</TableCell>
```

Comment: How are you using `filterBySearch`?

Comment: Fundamentally: 1. Remember the current filter. 2. Apply it when either the rows or the filter changes (`useMemo` is good for that).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder with an onChange event on an input - updated the code to show example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) is good for: Have an array of filtered rows, that you update as necessary when `rows` or `filters` changes:

```
const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<IDocument[]>([]);
const [rows, setRows] = useState<Data[]>([]);
// ...
const filteredRows = useMemo(
    () => rows.filter((document) => (
        document.documentAuthor.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentAuthor.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentName.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentName.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentSource.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentSource.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentType.includes(filters.documentType === 'All' ? '' : filters.documentType) &&
        document.featureId.includes(filters.featureId) 
    )),
    [rows, filters]
);
```

Then display `filteredRows`, not `rows`.

With that change, `filterBySearch` just sets the filter, it doesn't actually do the filtering:

```
const filterBySearch = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const newFilters = { ...filters, [name]: value };
    //Update filters with user input
    setFilters(newFilters);
};
```

`useMemo` will only call your callback when either `rows` or `filters` changes; otherwise, it'll just return the previous filtered array.

Here's a simplified demo — it shows words filtered by whatever you type in the filter, and randomly adds a word once every couple of seconds (this demonstrates that the filtering is repeated when the filter changes or when the rows change):

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef, useMemo } = React;

const words = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten".split(" ");

let nextRowId = 1;
const Example = () => {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(
        words.slice(0, 5).map((value) => ({ id: nextRowId++, value }))
    );
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
    const filteredRows = useMemo(() => {
        console.log(`Filtering rows`);
        if (!filter) {
            return rows;
        }
        return rows.filter((row) => row.value.includes(filter));
    }, [rows, filter]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let handle;
        tick();
        function tick() {
            handle = setTimeout(() => {
                const value = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
                console.log(`Adding "${value}"`);
                setRows((rows) => [...rows, { id: nextRowId++, value }]);
                tick();
            }, 2000);
        }
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(handle);
        };
    }, []);

    const filterChange = ({ currentTarget: { value } }) => {
        console.log(`Setting filter to "${value}"`);
        setFilter(value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Filter: <input type="text" value={filter} onChange={filterChange} />
            </div>
            Rows - showing {filteredRows.length} of {rows.length} total:
            <div>
                {filteredRows.map((row) => (
                    <div key={row.id}>{row.value}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

React's documentation says that `useMemo` is just for performance enhancement, it isn't a semantic guarantee (basically, React may call your callback even when nothing has actually changed). If you want a semantic guarantee, you can do it with a ref. You can even wrap that up into a hook that provides the semantic guarantee — I call it `useHardMemo`:

```
const useHardMemo = (fn, deps) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    let { current } = ref;
    if (current) {
        // Consistency check
        if (
            (deps && !current.deps) ||
            (!deps && current.deps) ||
            (deps && deps.length !== current.deps.length)
        ) {
            throw new Error(
                `Invalid call to useHardMemo, the dependency array must either always be present ` +
                    `or always be absent, and if present must always have the same number of items.`
            );
        }
    }
    if (!current || !deps?.every((dep, index) => Object.is(current.deps?.[index], dep))) {
        ref.current = current = {
            deps: deps?.slice(),
            value: fn(),
        };
    }
    return current.value;
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef, createElement } = React;

const useHardMemo = (fn, deps) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    let { current } = ref;
    if (current) {
        // Consistency check
        if (
            (deps && !current.deps) ||
            (!deps && current.deps) ||
            (deps && deps.length !== current.deps.length)
        ) {
            throw new Error(
                `Invalid call to useHardMemo, the dependency array must either always be present ` +
                    `or always be absent, and if present must always have the same number of items.`
            );
        }
    }
    if (!current || !deps?.every((dep, index) => Object.is(current.deps?.[index], dep))) {
        ref.current = current = {
            deps: deps?.slice(),
            value: fn(),
        };
    }
    return current.value;
};

const words = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten".split(" ");

let nextRowId = 1;
const Example = () => {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(
        words.slice(0, 5).map((value) => ({ id: nextRowId++, value }))
    );
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
    const filteredRows = useHardMemo(() => {
        console.log(`Filtering rows`);
        if (!filter) {
            return rows;
        }
        return rows.filter((row) => row.value.includes(filter));
    }, [rows, filter]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let handle;
        tick();
        function tick() {
            handle = setTimeout(() => {
                const value = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
                console.log(`Adding "${value}"`);
                setRows((rows) => [...rows, { id: nextRowId++, value }]);
                tick();
            }, 2000);
        }
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(handle);
        };
    }, []);

    const filterChange = ({ currentTarget: { value } }) => {
        console.log(`Setting filter to "${value}"`);
        setFilter(value);
    };

    // I'm using `createElement` because I had to turn off SO's hopelessly outdated Babel because
    // I wanted to be able to use optional chaining and such; so I couldn't use JSX.
    // return (
    //     <div>
    //         <div>
    //             Filter: <input type="text" value={filter} onChange={filterChange} />
    //         </div>
    //         Rows - showing {filteredRows.length} of {rows.length} total:
    //         <div>
    //             {filteredRows.map((row) => (
    //                 <div key={row.id}>{row.value}</div>
    //             ))}
    //         </div>
    //     </div>
    // );
    return createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            "Filter: ",
            createElement("input", { type: "text", value: filter, onChange: filterChange })
        ),
        `Rows - showing ${filteredRows.length} of ${rows.length} total:`,
        createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            filteredRows.map((row) => createElement("div", { key: row.id }, row.value))
        )
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(createElement(Example));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```